# How to call another function in jQuery from the hyperlink?

Tags: php, html, jquery, smarty

I'm having a link as follows :

```
<div id="demo-testpack">
          <a href="#" class="user-not-loggedin">Demo Test Packages</a>
      </div>
```

On clicking on this link I'm calling following jQuery code :

```
$(function() {  
  $("#user-popup-login").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); 
  $( ".user-not-loggedin" )
    .click(function() {
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "width", 400 );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
    $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "open" );

    return false;
  });
```

The pop up gets opened after this function some fields and some links are there in the pop up. One link is as follows in the popup:

```
<div id="registern"><a href="#" class="register-btn">Register Now</a></div>
```

On click of this link I want to execute the following code which results in opening of another popup. The jQuery code for this is as follows :

```
$(function() {  
    $("#create-user-form").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); 
    $( ".register-btn" )
        .click(function() {
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "option", "width", 560 );
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "open" );

        return false;
    });

    $( ".get-start" )
        .click(function() {
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "option", "width", 560 );
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog( "open" );

        return false;
    });         

    //This function is used to submit User Registration form
    $('#user_registration_form').live('submit', function() { 
         $('.register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         show_request('#registration_error');
            $.ajax({   
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'), 
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) { 
                    $('.register').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    var reg_error = response.reg_error;    

                    if(reg_error=='yes') {
                        var error_msg      = response.error_msg; 
                        var dialog_title   = 'Input Errors Found';                 
                        var dialog_message = error_msg; 
                        $("#registration_error").html(error_msg);
                    } else {
                        $("#registration_error").html('');
                        $( "#create-user-form" ).dialog('close');
                        var suc_msg   = response.suc_msg; 
                        var dialog_title   = 'Registered Successfully';                 
                        var dialog_message = suc_msg; 

                        var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                        .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                        .dialog({
                             autoOpen: false,
                             modal:true,
                             title: dialog_title,
                             width: 500,                       
                             buttons:{
                             'OK': function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                 }
                             }                                             
                        });
                        $dialog.dialog('open'); 
                        $('#user_registration_form')[0].reset();    
                    }

                } 
            });    
            return false;
    }); 
});
```

Now what I want to achieve is when user clicks on the above link the previously opened popup should close and only this new popup should display. I did lots of tricks but not succeeded. Can anyone help me out on how to achieve this?Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like an story! :D

Comment: @roasted:@roasted:Can you explain me with workable code?

Comment: No because i ask you if you can put your code in a jsfiddle to check it: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess this is scope issue because the call to `popup('open')` on `$( "#create-user-form" )` in a different anonymous function than where you are trying to close it. Try putting the calls to open and close it in the same document.ready shorthand anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but can you explain me with the help of code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried and reacThis can be achieved by following code snippet. It really did magic for me.

```
if($( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "open" ))
        $( "#user-popup-login" ).dialog( "close" );
```